# Show a 'loading placeholder' in Elm while it is rendering DOM elements

Tags: elm

When Elm has a lot of DOM manipulation to do, there is some lag before the results show up. I'm trying to figure out how to show a placeholder div that says "Loading..." while Elm is doing its thing.

To demonstrate the lag, I've modified one of the [Elm examples](http://elm-lang.org/examples/buttons) to render an increasingly huge number of text elements upon a button click:

```
import Html exposing (beginnerProgram, div, button, text)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick)

main =
  beginnerProgram { model = 0, view = view, update = update }


view model =
  div []
    [ button [ onClick Decrement ] [ text "-" ]
    , div [] [ text (toString model) ]
    , button [ onClick Increment ] [ text "+" ]
    , div [] (List.repeat (2 ^ model) (text ". ")) -- this is my addition
    ]

type Msg = Increment | Decrement

update msg model =
  case msg of
    Increment ->
      model + 1

    Decrement ->
      model - 1
```

When running the example, clicking the '+' button will show a '.' characters in powers of 2. When the number is sufficiently high (around 16 on my machine), there is a multi-second delay after clicking before the '.' characters are shown.

What is a good way to show a 'loading...' element (in a 'div', say) before rendering the '.' elements?

Comment: What I see from your example code is that actually browser rendering/layouting spends most of the waiting time, not by diffing of virtual DOM by js engine.  You may want to investigate how other frameworks(or simply by javascript DOM api calls) could handle it as it does not seem Elm specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use a regular `Html.program` and return a `Cmd` from the `Increment`/`Decrement` update handlers that will pause to let the DOM render the "Loading" and then reenter the `update`:

```elm
import Html exposing (program, div, button, text)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick)
import Process
import Task

main =
  program { init = (Model 0 False, Cmd.none), view = view, update = update, subscriptions = \_ -> Sub.none }

type alias Model =
  { count: Int
  , loading: Bool
  }

view model =
  let
    dotsDisplay =
      if model.loading then
        div [] [text "Loading..."]
      else
        div [] (List.repeat (2 ^ model.count) (text ". "))
  in
    div []
      [ button [ onClick Decrement ] [ text "-" ]
      , div [] [ text (toString model.count) ]
      , button [ onClick Increment ] [ text "+" ]
      , dotsDisplay
      ]

type Msg = Increment | Decrement | FinishLoading

finishLoadingCmd =
  Task.map2 (\_ b -> b) (Process.sleep 10) (Task.succeed FinishLoading)
  |> Task.perform identity

update msg model =
  case msg of
    Increment ->
      {model | count = model.count + 1, loading = True} ! [finishLoadingCmd]

    Decrement ->
      {model | count = model.count - 1, loading = True} ! [finishLoadingCmd]

    FinishLoading ->
      {model | loading = False} ! []
```

It's still going to lock up the browser while it renders all those nodes though, so you probably still want to look for a way to not be rendering 100k+ DOM elements...